# Best way to get most relevant data from table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an `entry` table with the columns as shown below:

```
id | ans_1 | ans_2 | ans_3   | ans_4    | ans_5   | date
```

Some sample data in the table as shown below:

```
1  | foo   | bar   | foobar  | bar foo  | foofoo  | 2011/9/15**
2  | foo2  | bar2  | foobar2 | bar2 foo | foofoo2 | 2011/9/17**
3  | foo3  | bar3  | foobar3 | bar foo3 | foo3foo | 2011/9/20**
```

I would like to search for the most relevant data from the `entry` table above provided by 5 answer sets.

My solution #1:

```
SELECT * FROM entry 
WHERE ans_1 LIKE '%$answer_set_1_en%' 
AND ans_2 LIKE '%answer_set_2_en%' 
AND ans_3 LIKE'%answer_set_3_en%' 
AND ans_4 LIKE '%answer_set_4_en%' 
AND ans_5 LIKE '%answer_set_5_en%';
```

However, I have 2 sets of answers (diff language sets) to compare now, here comes my solution for #2:

```
SELECT * FROM entry 
WHERE (ans_1 LIKE '%$answer_set_1_en%' 
AND ans_2 LIKE '%answer_set_2_en%' 
AND ans_3 LIKE '%answer_set_3_en%' 
AND ans_4 LIKE '%answer_set_4_en%' 
AND ans_5 LIKE '%answer_set_5_en%')
OR
(ans_1 LIKE '%$answer_set_1_jp%' 
AND ans_2 LIKE '%answer_set_2_jp%' 
AND ans_3 LIKE '%answer_set_3_jp%' 
AND ans_4 LIKE '%answer_set_4_jp%' 
AND ans_5 LIKE '%answer_set_5_jp%');
```

But, entry may mix with two languages, so my third attempts:

```
SELECT * FROM entry 
WHERE (
(ans_1 LIKE '%$answer_set_1_en%' OR ans_1 LIKE '%$answer_set_1_jp%') 
AND (ans_2 LIKE '%answer_set_2_en%' OR ans_2 LIKE '%$answer_set_2_jp%')
AND (ans_3 LIKE '%answer_set_3_en%' OR ans_3 LIKE '%$answer_set_3_jp%')
AND (ans_4 LIKE '%answer_set_4_en%' OR ans_4 LIKE '%$answer_set_4_jp%')
AND (ans_5 LIKE '%answer_set_5_en%' OR ans_5 LIKE '%$answer_set_5_jp%'));
```

Is the third query optimized/efficient enough already? May I know any other alternative ways of querying the most relevant columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow for a mix of english and japanes answeres then this looks like the way to go. Note that if you get a lot of entries this aproach will kill you, doing that many *LIKE* compares is going to be really slow.

Could you give examples on a valid answer_set?

Another approach is to do this same compare at the time of saving the entry (application side or with a trigger) that besides storing the actual answers also stores how many of them are correct. Then a simple

```
select * from entry where correct_answers = 5
```

is going to give you the wanted rows really quick.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your quick response, but I think this is the best I can get.